# How to read entity table name and primary key definition from fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent

We are using EF with configuration using FluentAPI. Our goal is to create an internationalization structure which allows creating tables containing names and descriptions of items in multiple idioms.

But for making it simple to programmers, the idea is creating some function to receive the entity definition and the attribute being internationalized, according to this sample:

```
public static new void CreateModel(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<City>().ToTable("Cities", "Common");
   modelBuilder.Entity<City>().Property(p => p.Acronym).HasMaxLength(20);
   modelBuilder.Entity<City>().Property(p => p.Acronym).IsOptional();
   modelBuilder.Entity<City>().Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired();
   modelBuilder.Entity<City>().HasRequired(c => c.State).WithMany(c => c.Cities).HasForeignKey(c => c.StateId);

   BuildLocalizedTable(modelBuilder, modelBuilder.Entity<City>, modelBuilder.Entity<City>().Property(p => p.Name));
}
```

In this code, you have the entity `City`, and the `BuildLocalizedTable()` function should read the table name and primary key definition from the parent entity, and declare the dependent entity, properties and navigation for having the name of the `City` in any other idiom.

After a lot of research, I could not find any sample for reading the entity definition, instead of writing. May this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Fluent API is available when you use EF Code-First approach. 
Code-First will create the database on the fly based on your entity classes and configuration. 
To configuration we can use DataAnnotations or Fluent API but the last one  provides more functionality.

There is no way to read entity definition using Fluent API because it just for configuration a new entities. We use Code-First so, we don't have any information about database because we first start by writing classes and then Code First APIs will create the new database